# where is the RubyGems remote server

Tags: ruby

Actually, not a question but the answer to something I was about to ask because I was only looking at documentation (my mistake) on docs.rubygems.org & google. I found the answer looking at the gem commands. The question was:

> Where is the remote server that RubyGems uses?

Answer - run the command:

`gem sources`  -- gives the info and allows you to add/remove remote sources. Also running

`gem environment`  -- will produce more information.

Comment: Answer goes in the answer box below, not in the question.  If you have answered your own question, it is possible to self-accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer - run the command:

`gem sources` -- gives the info and allows you to add/remove remote sources. Also running

`gem environment` -- will produce more information.

Comment: Now I know yet another thing, thanx.